# why program not reaching 'RET' or HALT' in LC3?

Tags: assembly, lc3

When the user presses ENTER(ASCII 10), the code should subtract 10 then branch to GSEND and go to halt but instead it is doing some weird loop. code follows:

```
.orig x3000
MAIN
    LEA R0, STR1 ;R0 points to STR1, which is the memory where we store the string.
    JSR GETSTR ;Get a string from the user
    PUTS ;Print the string
    HALT

    ;Data – Change these for testing
    .blkw 50 ;Change this value when testing between 50 and 150.

;Save space for string storage. Note that this effectively limits your string
;size to 50 which is the number of zs below.
STR1 .stringz "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

GETSTR

    ;save registers
    ST R2, GS_SR2
    ST R3, GS_SR3
    ST R4, GS_SR4

    LD R4, GS_LR4

    ADD R2, R0, #0

GSTOP

    GETC ;get character

    ADD R3, R0, R4 ;if newline skip to end
    BRZ GSEND

    STR R0, R2, #0 ;store letter in STR1
    OUT

    ADD R2, R2, #1 ;increment R2
    BRNZP GSTOP


GSEND


    ADD R0, R2, #0
    ;reset registers
    LD R2, GS_SR2
    LD R3, GS_SR3


    RET


GS_SR0  .fill 0
GS_SR2  .fill 0
GS_SR3  .fill 0
GS_SR4  .fill 0

GS_LR4  .fill -10


    .end
```

code should reprint the entire string and halt. i can't tell if it just never reaches RET or is getting sent somewhere else.

Comment: What happened when you single stepped it in your simulator?

Comment: My simulator seems to use `CR` (code 13) not `LF` (code `10`) for the enter so maybe change that. Better yet, check for both.

Comment: Furthermore you need to preserve `R7` otherwise you won't be able to `RET` (which is the cause of your endless loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSR` instruction performs a call.  A call does two things: transfers control to the designated label, and also, puts the place (here in `main`, a code address) to return to in `R7`.  In order for `GETSTR` to successfully return to `main`, it must have that same return address that `main` put into `R7` via the `JSR` instruction.

However, it does not, because the trap invoking instruction (here `GETC`) repurposes `R7` for the return address from the trap.  So, in some sense, use of `GETC` wipes out one `R7` value so that `GETC` can use `R7` to return back to `GETSTR`.  So, when `GETSTR` tries to use `R7` via `RET`, it returns not to where should go, but to the return address in `R7`, which is within `GETSTR` right after the `GETC` since that is how `R7` was last used — hence the weird loop.

Just need to save & restore `R7` the same way as some of the other registers already being done.